# How to loop python to read a set of HTML files and dump into JSON

Tags: python, html, json, loops, beautifulsoup

I have a program that extracts certain variables from a group of 20 html files. Can someone give me advice on how to loop the program to read all the html files from a directory and print the information in individual json documents?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#opens data file
get_data = open("book1.html",'r').read()


#parses the html
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_data)

# finds title and author

title = soup.find("span", id="btAsinTitle")
author = title.find_next("a", href=True)

# finds price
for definition in soup.findAll('span', {"class":'bb_price'}):
    definition = definition.renderContents()

#finds ISBN, Shipping Weight, Product Dimensions
print soup.find('b', text='ISBN-10:').next_sibling
print soup.find('b', text='Shipping Weight:').next_sibling


#prints all the information

print definition
print title.get_text()
print author.get_text()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`glob.iglob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to loop through all `html` files in a directory. For every filename, pass the file-like object to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor, get the elements you need and construct a dictionary:

```
import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for filename in glob.iglob('*.html'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

        title = soup.find("span", id="btAsinTitle")
        author = title.find_next("a", href=True)
        isbn = soup.find('b', text='ISBN-10:').next_sibling
        weight = soup.find('b', text='Shipping Weight:').next_sibling

        print {'title': title.get_text(),
               'author': author.get_text(),
               'isbn': isbn,
               'weight': weight}
```

Comment: This is a great answer but do you know how to export these variables to json?

Comment: @user2962786 yup, you can do it using [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) or [`json.dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump).

Answer (score 2):

To process set of files in some directory:

```
from glob import glob
fnames = glob("datadir/*.html")
for fname in fnames:
  html2json(fname)
```

Now we need the function html2json, it shall get name of html file and will write json string to a file with the same name as has the html, but with added json extension.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def html2json(fname):
  resdct = {}
  with open(fname) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

    title = soup.find("span", id="btAsinTitle")
    resdct["title"] = title.get_text()
    resdct["author"] = title.find_next("a", href=True).get_text()
    resdct["isbn"] = soup.find('b', text='ISBN-10:').next_sibling.get_text()
    resdct["weight"] = soup.find('b', text='Shipping Weight:').next_sibling.get_text()

  outfname = fname + ".json"
  with open(outfname, "w") as f:
    json.dump(resdct, f)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response but does it dump a new file into the directory? I can't find an output file

Comment: @user2962786 Good hit, I had there an error, missing "w" mode in last open. Corrected. Try again.